# »Jmd. ähnlich sehen« vs. »ähnlich aussehen« und »wie jemand aussehen«

Tags: translation, meaning, difference

Wenn ich richtig es verstanden habe, wird *jemandem ähnlich sehen* als *to resemble someone* ins Englische übersetzt, also:

> Er sieht mir ähnlich. – He resembles me.

Wieso wird in diesem Fall nicht Folgendes benutzt?

> Er sieht ähnlich mir aus.

Und noch was: Sind *jemandem ähnlich sehen* und *wie jemand aussehen* fast austauschbar? Zum Beispiel:

> Er sieht einem Affe ähnlich.
>   Er sieht aus wie eine Affe.

Comment: Die Grammatik Deiner Beispiele ist in der Tat voll durcheinander (was aber nicht schlimm ist), aber der Rest Deiner Frage dreht sich um die Bedeutung, oder? Kannst Du bitte klarstellen, ob es Dir um die Grammatik oder die Bedeutung geht? (Falls Du nach beidem fragen möchtest, stelle lieber separate Fragen.)

Comment: Es geht vor allem um die Bedeutung. Könntest du mir bitte die einzelne grammatischer Fehler aufzeigen. Ich wäre sehr dankbar.

Comment: Ich habe die Grammatikfrage entfernt sowie die Grammatikfehler korrigiert. Letztere haben vor allem mit der Wortstellung zu tun, die ich nicht allzu gut erklären kann (das Stichwort ist *trennbare Verben).* Überprüfe bitte, ob alles in Ordnung ist.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In der Tat kann man »he resembles me« mit »er sieht mir ähnlich« übersetzen. Weitere Möglichkeiten wären »er ähnelt mir« und »er sieht so aus wie ich«. Doch »er sieht mir ähnlich aus« solltest du nicht sagen; keiner sagt das. Stattdessen kannst du Folgendes sagen:

- > A: »Schau mal, ich habe einen neuen Stift.«
  >   B: »Hey, der sieht so ähnlich aus wie meiner.«
- > A: »Was ist das Problem? Warum kannst du den neuen Staubsauger nicht bedienen? Der letzte hat dir auch keine Schwierigkeiten bereitet.«
  >   B: »Er sieht zwar ähnlich aus, aber glaube mir, er funktioniert ganz anders.«

Was *jmd. ähnlich sehen* anbelangt, fragst du dich eventuell, wie man überhaupt *sehen* so gebrauchen kann, denn eigentlich bedeutet das Verb ja ungefähr:

> visuelle Informationen verarbeiten, die über Nerven vom Auge zum Gehirn weitergeleitet wurden

In dem Fall musst du einfach auswendig lernen, dass *jmd. ähnlich sehen* eine eigene Bedeutung hat; und der Sprung von *sehen* zu *aussehen* ist nicht groß. (Genaueres kann ich dir bezüglich der Etymologie leider nicht sagen.)

Und zu deiner letzten Frage: Ja, die Ausdrücke *jemandem ähnlich sehen* und *wie jemand aussehen* sind austauschbar. Wenn es überhaupt einen Unterschied gibt, dann ist dieser sehr subtil. Man muss aber das Verb *ähnlichsehen* von dem Ausdruck *ähnlich sehen* unterscheiden! *Ähnlichsehen* bedeutet hierbei *zu jemandes Charakter passen:*

- > A: »Wie konnte Tim nur auf die absurde Idee kommen, seine Boxershorts in den Kühlschrank zu legen? Wer macht so etwas?«
  >   B: »Oh, das sieht ihm ähnlich. Daran musst du dich gewöhnen. Du wirst bald feststellen, dass er anders ist, und zwar in vielerlei Hinsicht.«
- > A: »Ich habe einen anonymen Brief erhalten, auf dem unzählige Schimpfwörter stehen. Das habe ich nicht verdient!«
  >   B: »Ich glaube, das war Tim.«
  >   A: »Warum?«
  >   B: »Ach, diese Gemeinheit würde ihm ähnlichsehen.«